Propensity Score Matching and Weighted Regression Analysis
I have a dataset of ~N=1000 and I want to estimate the average causal/treatment effect of an exposure on an outcome.
I've used propensity score matching to balance baseline covariates, and my matched dataset is now ~N=600 (300 exposure and 300 unexposed).
I now wish to estimate the effect of exposure on the outcome of interest, using regression, and I'm wondering whether I should perform a weighted regression analysis using inverse probability weights (based on the propensity score) - similar to what is discussed in this post.
I'm using R, and when I use a weighted regression analysis, the effect estimates are different compared to when I just run regular regression (which is not unexpected). But I'm just not sure if I'm correct to add a weight statement to my regression code when my dataset is already matched based on the propensity score?

You did PS matching, and you are asking if you should do PS weighting in the matched dataset? If your matching was successful and you re-estimate the propensity score in the matched sample, all units should have a propensity score close to .5, in which case weighting won't do anything anyway. If you didn't get good balance after matching, why not try a different method of matching? Why not just use weighting? Did you read the MatchIt documentation, which explains how to estimate effects after matching?

Hi Noah, thanks for your reply. I successfully performed NN PS matching yes, from which we can estimate the average treatment effect on the treated (as noted in the MatchIt documentation you linked)... but if I want to estimate the average treatment effect in the population, should I weight my regression analysis using IPW? I have read this in a few papers (including Stuart 2010), and then saw something similar in a post here (linked above). Thanks again

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

If you want the ATE, you can't use pair matching, as it can only be used to target the ATT. You have to estimate the weights in the full sample, not the matched sample. See the WeightIt documentation if you need help doing so.

Both propensity matching an weighting are inefficient.
